# GetAbsolutePathName problem about getting the wrong path directory (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I expect to get the full path directory, but I got the short path from `GetAbsolutePathName` function. How can I get the full directory path?

This is MS excel pro plus 2016. I put my basic coding below:

```vb
Dim FileName as String
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
FileName = fso.GetAbsolutePathName("cmdResources")
```

Expect output is:

> C:\Users\myName\Documents\A\B\C\D\E\F\cmdResources

Actual output is:

> C:\Users\myName\Documents\cmdResources

Comment: Have a read on [getabsolutepathname-method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getabsolutepathname-method). What's wrong with using the `Path` from workbook?

Comment: @FAB yes, I read already and I didn't get the full path. My folders A\B\C\D\E\F is not shown.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Path`?

Comment: @JohnyL not that point, sir. In my case, I would like to get the path of my specific directory.

Comment: That method won't do what you want with the input of just a filename.  How are you inputting the filename?  If it is just some random filename that you are typing in, then you'll need to search the computer (or some designated folder) for that filename.  If you are inputting that data using some other method, then there might be a simpler way of getting the full path.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I was trying to put more path to let system know ,but it didn't come for the full path for example: 
```FileName = fso.GetAbsolutePathName("C\D\E\F\cmdResources")```

The output is as below:
```
C:\Users\myName\Documents\C\D\E\F\cmdResources
```
That's mean I didn't get folder ```\A\B```

Comment: Again, that's not how that method works.  If I were trying to find the location of a particular file, I would Shell to the `CMD` window and use the `DIR` command with the `/S` switch, and possibly wild cards.  Then extract the full path from the returned information.  Probably be faster than using the FSO.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I got it. However, thank you very much for you explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want VBA to "search" for a file/folder in a directory, I think you need to use something like this:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Public Enum xlSearchMode
    xlFilesOnly = 0
    xlFoldersOnly = 1
    xlFilesAndFolders = 2
End Enum
Function SearchInDirectory(FName As String, Optional FoName As String, Optional SearchMode As xlSearchMode = xlFilesOnly, Optional ExactMatch As Boolean = True) As Variant
    'By Abdallah Khaled Ali El-Yaddak
    'Returns an array of strings with files/folders matching what you are searching for.
    'If nothing is found, it returns an array of one empty string element.
    '-------------'
    'FName (String): The file/folder to look for
    '[FoName] (String): The directory to search in, if omitted, CurDir will be used.
    '[SreachMode] (xlSearchMode): xlFilesOnly (default) = Look for files only | xlFoldersOnly = Look for folders only | xlFilesAndFolders = Look for both
    '[Exactmatch] (Boolean): True (default) = Look only for this string (case insenstive) | False = Sreach for any files/folders that includes this string in their name
    Dim FSO As Object, File As Object, Folder As Object, Fnames() As String, i As Long, SubNames As Variant, SubFolder As Object
    If FoName = "" Then FoName = CurDir
    If Right(FoName, 1) <> "\" Then FoName = FoName & "\"
    ReDim Fnames(1 To 1) As String
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder(FoName)
    If SearchMode = xlFilesOnly Or SearchMode = xlFilesAndFolders Then
        For Each File In FSO.GetFolder(Folder).Files
            If (ExactMatch And SubFolder.Name = FName) Or _
                    (Not ExactMatch And SubFolder.Name Like "*" & FName & "*") Then
                Fnames(UBound(Fnames)) = File.Path
                ReDim Preserve Fnames(1 To UBound(Fnames) + 1)
            End If
        Next
    End If
    If SearchMode = xlFoldersOnly Or SearchMode = xlFilesAndFolders Then
        For Each SubFolder In FSO.GetFolder(Folder).subFolders
            If (ExactMatch And SubFolder.Name = FName) Or _
                    (Not ExactMatch And SubFolder.Name Like "*" & FName & "*") Then
                Fnames(UBound(Fnames)) = SubFolder.Path
                ReDim Preserve Fnames(1 To UBound(Fnames) + 1)
            End If
        Next
    End If
    For Each SubFolder In FSO.GetFolder(Folder).subFolders
        SubNames = SearchInDirectory(FName, SubFolder.Path, SearchMode, ExactMatch)
        If SubNames(LBound(SubNames)) <> "" Then
            For i = LBound(SubNames) To UBound(SubNames)
                Fnames(UBound(Fnames)) = SubNames(i)
                ReDim Preserve Fnames(1 To UBound(Fnames) + 1)
            Next
        End If
    Next
    If UBound(Fnames) > 1 Then ReDim Preserve Fnames(1 To UBound(Fnames) - 1)
    SearchInDirectory = Fnames
End Function
```

To test, you need something like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim a As Variant, i As Long
    a = SearchInDirectory("cmdResources", "C:\Users\myName\Documents\A", SearchMode:=xlFoldersOnly)
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        Debug.Print a(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

**Notes:**

1. This solution doesn't work on MAC (tested only on windows)
2. Searching will take longer for larger directories (The number of files/folders inside)

Comment: Thanks for your codes, and I am trying to use them. Unfortunately, I got an error "Permission denied" so, I checked with FoName which shown as "C:\Users\myName\Documents\My Music\". Even I was trying to change the directory to "C:\Users\myName\Documents\A", it still shown as error.

Comment: Did you try it like this? `SearchInDirectory("cmdResources", "C:\Users\myName\Documents\A", SearchMode:=xlFoldersOnly)`
Which line is highlighted when the "Permission denied" error appears?
And did you make sure you selected the right value for `SearchMode` parameter?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.